# Building an interface for STL vector

Tags: c++, stl

I'm looking at building a wrapper for the C++ STL container vector (there will be more functionality then a vector can provide (load, save, etc.) so it needs to be a wrapper).

Consumers of my wrapper need to iterate though the elements and if I expose STL iterators changing the implementation later would require my callers to recompile (plus I feel like I'm breaking encapsulation).

I would like to create an interface which only returns primitive types to ensure clients will not need to recompile if I change the implementation. I was thinking about exposing the vector size as an integer (similar to how MFC CArray does) and also overloading the [ ] operator and the callers can loop the vector that way.

My questions:

1. If I want to return an int for the vector size how does that work with size_type? Size_type isn't seem feel like it should be exposed in an interface since if it changes the caller will need to recompile. I'd be happy to impose some sort of limit if it turns out size_type can be larger then an integer (I don't expect I'll ever have that many elements!)
2. Is looping a vector using the [ ] operator significantly worse then using iterators

*Edited:* Removed the word 'generic' - this has nothing to do with templates, it's just a class. Also clarified "exposes primitive types" to mean a method returning an int not the data member itself.

Comment: Using iterators and `size_type` is _more_ generic than using integer indexes and `operator []`. Iterators abstract away the type of the container and `size_type` allows the size value to be any integral type.

Comment: If I change the implementation later on to use something like Boost, clients who have been using my STL iterators would need to recompile wouldn't they?

Comment: You could write your own wrapper for the iterators just like you are with the vector. But yes, if the type of `size_type` changes and that is exposed they will have to recompile.

Comment: @Cube: The fact that you're using *templates* means that any change to your implementation will force a recompile. Best get used to that now. And if you're not using templates, then you're using the word "generic" wrong.

Comment: @Nicol: Thank you. I've removed references to 'generic', my intention was an interface that only uses the primative types so I could change the class without callers needing to recompile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an singelton ifc (pure virtual) class that your clients will reference. I think this design model is called "Singelton factory approach".
I hope my long answer will help you :).

As long as you're not changing the public interface (method lists) your clients would not need to recompile if you change your code.

something like:

myClassIfc.h:

```
Class myClassIfc
{
public:
    virtual ~myClassIfc();    

    ///// list all your pure virtual public ifc methods here ////
    void m_zRunMyMethod(int nNumber) = 0;
    int m_nSize() = 0;

    static myClassIfc* ms_pGetImplObj();      

protected:        
    myClassIfc();
    static myClassIfc* ms_pImplObj;
}

inline myClassIfc* myClassIfc::ms_pGetImplObj()
{
    return ms_pImplObj;
}
```

myClassIfc.cpp:

```
#include myClassIfc.h

myClassIfc::myClassIfc()
{
}
myClassIfc::~myClassIfc()
{
}
```

myClass.h - implement your pure virtual class

```
Class myClass: public myClassIfc
{
public:
    virtual ~myClass();    

    void m_zRunMyMethod(int nNumber);
    int m_nSize();

    static void ms_zCreate();
    static void ms_zDestroy();

protected:        
    myClass();

private:
    vector<int> myInternalVector;
}
```

myClass.cpp:

```
#include myClass.h

void myClass::m_zRunMyMethod(int nNumber)
{
   /// your action
   printf("%d\n", nNumber);
}

int myClass::m_nSize()
{
   return int(myInternalVector.size());
}

void myClass::ms_zCreate()
{
    if (NULL != ms_pImplObj)
    {
        return;
    }
    ms_pImplObj = (myClass*) new myClass();   
}

void myClass::ms_zDestroy()
{
    if (NULL == ms_pImplObj)
    {
        return;
    }
    delete ms_pImplObj;
    ms_pImplObj = NULL;
}
```

Now after the above long infrastructure work, your clients need to use

```
#include myClassIfc.h


void main(void)
{
    myClassIfc::ms_pGetImplObj()->m_zRunMyMethod(5);
    myClassIfc::ms_pGetImplObj()->m_nSize();         
}
```

the only thing i didn't listed above is your memory management, which means who creates the singleton object itself (invoke the ms_zCreate() static API of the derived class).
you can either call it from elsewhere, or directly from your code.

Notice you can manipulate the above ifc approach to be non singelton implementation.
As long as the ifc class is not changing, the client code will not need a recompile if you modify the derive (implementation) class.

Comment: Better is to pimpl and forward rather than using inheritance to attempt to hide implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't suggest using the index and operator[] actually. Instead of exposing the vector iterators directly, create iterator typedefs in your class that initially just equate to the vector iterators but you can change it to anything you want without requiring code changes by your clients. Then you can use the normal begin/end/find methods.

Comment: I understand they won't need to change code but will they need to recompile if the typedef is changed?

Comment: Yes. The only way to possibly avoid recompiling is to also create your own corresponding iterator wrappers, and hide the entire implementation in a source file. Just remember that ABI breakage (and thus forcing a recompile anyway) is pretty hard to avoid in C++.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of what you are asking that flies in the face of modern C++ design. I will refer you to Herb Stutter and Andrei Alexandrescu's book [C++ Coding Standards](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm). Examine these chapter titles on class design:

```
Class Design and Inheritance
32. Be clear what kind of class you’re writing. 56
33. Prefer minimal classes to monolithic classes. 57
34. Prefer composition to inheritance. 58
35. Avoid inheriting from classes that were not designed to be base classes. 60
38. Practice safe overriding. 66
39. Consider making virtual functions nonpublic, and public functions nonvirtual. 68
41. Make data members private, except in behaviorless aggregates (C-style structs). 72
42. Don’t give away your internals. 74
44. Prefer writing nonmember nonfriend functions. 79
```

Pay particular attention to #44. Instead of overriding the STL Vector, create nonmember functions that operate on STL iterators. This also ties into #35. STL classes are not really designed to be base classes. #33 is the reason I cringe at your comment that you want to add "Load" and "save" functions to the STL vector. Those kinds of functions sound like they should be nonmember functions.

Oh, and have you really thought this through:

> I would like to create an interface which only exposes primitive types to ensure clients will not need to recompile if I change the implementation. I was thinking about exposing the vector size as an integer

On the one hand, you want to use composition to hide the vector inside another class. Okay. Not the most flexible design but perhaps you need to interface with non-C++ code. But then you want to expose a data member of your class as part of the interface. That can create issues where your clients will need to recompile. That doesn't make sense. Either you want total encapsulation or don't care about frequent recompiles. Which is it? (And please, don't model anything on the MFC CArray class. It's terrible.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have to expose the size, that was just one way I could think that would allow clients to iterate though the array using the [] operator. I was looking at a method that would return an integer representing the size of the array (not exposing the data member) because from looking at various APIs and their entry points retuning an int seems safe and common.

Comment: @Cube, STL Vector already has such a method: size(). It is a const method returning size_type, which is generally defined as size_t, which is generally an unsigned int.

Answer (score 0):

You say "I would like to create an interface which only exposes
primitive types to ensure clients will not need to recompile."  Just the
opposite is true; if you want to avoid recompilation, you need to make
everything a user defined type, using the compilation firewall idiom.
In the case of iterators, this may have an unacceptable performance
penalty: the iterator idiom requires deep copy, and the fact that
nothing can be inlined is likely to affect optimization as well.

I think avoiding recompilation totally is probably not reasonable, given
the way C++ works.  More important is that you want to avoid requiring 
modifications in client code if you change the implementation.  In this
case, for example, you want to define exactly what you want to
guarantee; if you decide that iterators into your class must be random
access iterators, then a typedef to `std::vector<>::iterator` is
probably sufficient; if all you want to guarantee is forward iteration
(to allow more freedom in the implementation later), you want to
consider wrapping the `std::vector<>::iterator` in your own iterator,
which only exposes the operations for which you are willing to guarantee
support in all future versions.

Note that if you later decide to use an implementation which doesn't
support random access iterators, you can't support `[]` either.
Supporting `[]` imposes more constraints on future implementations than
supporting just forward iterators.